# Create a header in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, headers, email-signature

I am setting up my boss's email accounts on Outlook 2007.

He was wondering if it's possible to have a default header on each new email, just like a signature. So when he composes a new email the shop logo will automatically appear at the top.

I tried using multiple signatures but that didn't work.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to adjust the default email template.  Here is the path to the Normal Email.dotm file.

C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Templates

Comment: Thanks,  it seemed to have work,  sorry for the late response :)